# Find array difference using loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in PHP. I want to find array difference without using any array function like `array_diff()` or `in_array()`.

This is my code

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d','k');
$b = array('g','h','i','b','a','d','c');
$match = array();
$miss_match = array();

$count_a = count($a);
$count_b = count($b);

for($i=0; $i<$count_a;$i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j<$count_b;$j++)
            {
            if($a[$i]==$b[$j])
                {
                $match[] = $a[$i];
                break;
                }
            else
                {
                $miss_match[] = $b[$j];
                }   
            }
    }
print_r($match).'<br />';
print_r($miss_match);
```

And I am getting this result

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d ) 
Array ( [0] => g [1] => h [2] => i [3] => b [4] => g [5] => h 
[6] => i [7] => g [8] => h [9] => i [10] => b [11] => a [12] => d 
[13] => g [14] => h [15] => i [16] => b [17] => a [18] => g 
[19] => h [20] => i [21] => b [22] => a [23] => d [24] => c )
```

My expected result is

> Array ( [0] => g [1] => h [2] => i [3] => k )

Please suggest better solution.Thanks

Comment: Why you want to do something which can be easily done by pre defined functions?

Comment: "I want to find array difference without using any array function like array_diff() or in_array()." **Why? If there is a solution that works, why not use it?**

Comment: In your else-branch you are adding the current element of $b to your mismatch-array each time it does not match the _current_ element of $a …

Comment: Because using array_diff is easier? and faster?

Comment: `array_diff()` will only give one result, whereas your expected output has 3 values. What's the difference?

Comment: @Mr. Alien and @h I know that i can do this by using array functions but I want this solution for technical improvement. Please suggest solution. Thanks

Comment: I applaud him, he's trying to learn some general array processing techniques. He'll need this background when he needs to do things that aren't available in built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the element to the `miss_match` array for every element of the other array that it doesn't match. But if it doesn't match this element, it might still match a later element.

You have to go through the entire array before determining that it doesn't match any of them.

```
for($i=0; $i<$count_a;$i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<$count_b;$j++)
    {
        $matched = false;
        if($a[$i]==$b[$j])
        {
            $match[] = $a[$i];
            $matched = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$matched)
    {
        $miss_match[] = $a[$i];
    }   
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
Array
(
    [0] => k
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new code for find array difference using loop

```
$b = array('a','b','c','d','x','b');
$a = array('g','h','i','b','a','d','c');
$mismatch = array();
$count_a = count($a);
$count_b = count($b);
$match = array();
for( $i = 0; $i<count($a); $i++ )
{
        $found_a ='no';
        $foundss ='no';
        for($j=0; $j<count($b); $j++ )
        {
             if($a[$i] == $b[$j])
             {
                 $found_a ='yes';
                 $match[]=$a[$i];
            }            

        }
        if($found_a =='no')
        {
             for($t=0;$t<count($mismatch);$t++)
            {
                if($a[$i]== $mismatch[$t])
                   {
                       $foundss ='yes';
                       break;

                    }
            }
                if($foundss == 'no')
                {  
                    $mismatch[]=$a[$i];
                } 

        }

}

for($z=0; $z< count($b); $z++)
{ $found_b ='no';
$found_match ='no';
   for($t=0;$t<count($mismatch);$t++)
    {
        if($b[$z]==$mismatch[$t])
        {
             $found_b ='yes';
        }    
    }
    if($found_b =='no')
    {
        for($d =0; $d<count($match);$d++)
                   {
                     if($b[$z] ==$match[$d] )  
                     {
                         $found_match='yes';
                         $break;
                     } 
                   }
                if($found_match=='no')   
        $mismatch[]=$b[$z];
    }
}
print_r($mismatch);
```